# inserting value of a struct to pair in C++

Tags: c++

I have read in the C++ reference for map insertion and in the example is shown the following code

```
std::map<char,int> mymap;
mymap.insert (it, std::pair<char,int>('b',300));
```

while at the same time I saw a code of a similar operation with

```
mymap.insert( pair<uuid,structval>( (*it).first, structval() ) );
```

The structval itself is declared as a normal structure

```
    struct structval { 
//some params 
};
```

Can anyone please explain me why to initiate the pair of structval we can simply call the structure by using structval() operation? What does structval() there means? Is this a valid way to access a struct and put it as a pair?

Thank you

Comment: Not an answer, but a little comment: 1) `std::pair(...)` is the same thing as `structval()` but with parameters)) 2) in most cases it's easy to use helper function `std::make::pair` instead of `std::pair< Type1, Type2>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What does structval() there means? Is this a valid way to access a struct and put it as a pair?

`structval()` instantiates a *temporary* object of type `structval`. Therefore, technically, it is not a way to *access a struct*, but to create an instance of it. And yes, it is a valid way to create an instance of an object:

```
struct X 
{ 
    X() : i_(42) { } 

    int i_;
};

void foo(X x) { /* ... */ }

// ...

foo(X()); // <== Valid way to construct a temporary object
          //     of type X and pass it as an argument to
          //     the foo() function.
```

This temporary, default-constructed instance is then passed as an argument to the constructor of `std::pair` (and by the way, the pair object you are constructing is also a temporary!).

Usually, pairs are constructed by calling the `std::make_pair()` function, that can deduce the type of the arguments for you, so you don't have to type them explicitly. Therefore, you could rewrite this:

```
pair<uuid,structval>( (*it).first, structval() )
```

As the following:

```
std::make_pair((*it).first, structval())
```

In C++11 you could also use the [`emplace`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/emplace) member function instead of `insert()`:

```
mymap.emplace((*it).first, structval());
```

This would make it unnecessary to explicitly construct the pair (or to invoke `std::make_pair()` for that purpose).

---

As a final remark, the value type of a map is not:

```
pair<key_type, mapped_type>
```

But rather:

```
pair<key_type const, mapped_type>
//            ^^^^^
```

Because a map's keys shall never be changed, in order to prevent messing up with the internal ordering of the container.

Comment: It also works for non-struct types. `float()` is another way to write `0.0f`.

Answer (score 0):

`structval()` is a call of constructor of type `structval` without parameters. So, simply use temporary created object.

Related: you should use `std::make_pair`, instead of call pair c-tor in most cases.